# Remove value display from eCharts4R gauge chart

Tags: r, echarts4r

Given this example

```
library(echarts4r)
library(magrittr)

gauge_out <- e_charts() %>%
  e_gauge(41,"Percent")

print(gauge_out)
```

You get this gauge chart

[image]

I'd like to NOT have the number "41" displayed at the bottom.  From looking through the eCharts docs if there's a quick way to do that I seem to be missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...

```
library(echarts4r)
library(magrittr)

gauge_out <- e_charts() %>%
  e_gauge(41,"Percent", 
          detail = list(
            show = FALSE
          ))

print(gauge_out)
```